# Фоновая музыка в играх и приложениях, каковы лучшие практики. Библиотеки

Tags: java, android

Основной мой вопрос в том, что я хочу понять архитектуру подобного приложения. Какие классы и с каким отношением встроить.

В игрушку собираюсь добавить фоновую музыку и естественно к такому плееру нужно иметь доступ из разных классов, например я в меню - играет один трэк, перешел в игровое поле - трэк другой или же из игрового поля иметь возможность приглушить фоновую музыку, а на первый план вывести звуки из игры
, произошло игровое событие - воспроизвел другой звук ( в последнем случае, наверно нужно создавать второй экземпляр класса для воспроизведения и раз такие звуки привязаны к игровому полю, думаю достаточен один  `SoundPool` используя композицию)  Для класса `MediaPlayer` так и напрашивается использовать шаблон ***синглтон***. Еще вопрос: учитывая, что в приложениях часто, и так же в моем случае, воспроизведение музыки должно прекращаться при сворачивании приложения, то нужен ли мне `Service`?  Думаю что нет. 
 
В любом случае `MediaPlayer` должен находиться в доп. потоке, а значит нужен способ общения с этим потоком, как это всё правильно реализуется?  И есть ли какие то связанные с темой воспроизведения музыки библиотеки?

Comment: может ошибусь, но если попробовать так: инициализировать модуль работы с фоновой музыкой через Dagger на уровне всего приложения, тогда по сути из любого места приложения можно получать доступ к модулю и работать с ним...

Comment: Я примерно знаю зачем нужна библиотека Dagger, но пользоваться и изучать я её еще не начал. Но из слов "инициализировать на уровне всего приложения" вытекает, что вы предлагаете использовать singleton, а я же спрашиваю, есть ли еще какие нибудь решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно воспроизведение звука и в момент когда приложение свернуто, то нужно конечно использовать `Service`. Если пишем какой нибудь плеер используем класс `MediaController`, он обрабатывает обратные вызовы от аппаратных кнопок, от подключенной гарнитуры и так далее,  в общем полный контроль над воспроизведением музыки. Вот хорошая  [статья](https://habr.com/post/339416/)  на этот случай.

---

В случае описываемом в вопросе, когда воспроизведение звука нужно только в открытом приложении и должно контролироваться из разных активностей, применяем шаблон синглтон. (Думаю не стоит искать решение лучше так как для этого шаблон одиночка и существует. Альтернативой было бы передавать из одной активности в другую экземпляр `MediaPlayer` и писать лишний код)  Т.е. создаем класс в котором есть экземпляр `MediaPlayer` и обращаемся к нему из любой активности. Как реализовать шаблон одиночка в андроид есть [тут](https://habr.com/post/129494/) , вот [статья](https://ru-code-android.livejournal.com/4594.html) о правильной реализации этого шаблона в Java.

---

А теперь насчет того в каком потоке с этим MediaPlayer работать. Само воспроизведение музыки процесс не ресурсоемкий, поэтому можно смело стартовать в главном потоке. А вот загрузка этого ресурса может занимать время. Если ресурс находится в самом приложении или это какой нибудь файл с флешки, то смело работаем в главном потоке, если это загрузка по сети или поток, то для нас у 
`MediaPlayer` есть метод `prepareAsync()`, который произведет подготовку ресурса в отдельном потоке, а по завершению вернет `CallBack`. В прочем [вот](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/236-urok-126-media-mediaplayer-audiovideo-pleer-osnovnye-vozmozhnosti.html) разбор `MediaPlayer`

Насчет библиотек: я ничего не искал, т.к.  MediaPlayer это уже так сказать библиотека, в нем реализовано всё самое основное.

Answer (score 0):

Ну а для простых звуков, если небольшой длительности,  в игре лучше использовать  класс AudioTrack, а файлы готовить в PCM формате. Будет быстрее реакция на действия в игре. А фоновую музыку использовать MediaPlayer.